# Counting numbers of words found in a text string based on Array keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote the following code, while it works, it is very inefficient and would be open to critique/rework. Main problem is it's a nightmare to scale.

```
function wordCount(layers) {
    var countNum = '3'

    if (layers.includes('Text1') && layers.includes('Text2') && layers.includes('Text3,')) {
        return countNum - 3;
    } else if (layers.includes('Text1') && layers.includes('Text2')) {
        return countNum - 2;
    } else if (layers.includes('Text1') && layers.includes('Text3,')) {
        return countNum - 2;
    } else if (layers.includes('Text2') && layers.includes('Text3,')) {
        return countNum - 2;
    } else if (layers.includes('Text1') || layers.includes('Text2') || layers.includes('Text3,')) {
        return countNum - 1;
    }
    return countNum;
} 
console.log(wordCount('Layer 1, Text1')); //return 2
```

Below is what i've tried so far, but haven't been able to figure out how to count the numbers of words from an array found in a string.

```
function wordCount() {
    let keywords = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4', 'Text5']
    let textString = 'Layer1, Text1, Text5'
    let count = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        console.log(keywords[i].length); // when running code as-is return 5.
        return textString.split(", ").length;  
    }
}
console.log(wordCount());; // when running code as-is return 3.
//I'm expecting the return to be 2.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just keep your key words in a static array and interrogate any given string for a match count?

Comment: Your second code block makes no sense. It's not using `keywords[i]` for anything, and returning immediately during the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Why is 2 the correct result in the first block? It only matches 1 word. Why are you subtracting the number of matches from 3?

Comment: What about case sensitivity?

Comment: @mwilson, Thank you or your response. I know very basic JS so I don't even know what you mean by keeping keywords as static and interrogate. I'll have to look that up.

Comment: @Barmar, My second block was me trying things out... I was trying to piece things together from the limited knowledge I have.

Comment: @MarkC., Not too worried about case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` with `Array.includes()` to get the number. Since the list of words might change, you can create a function with partial application, that accepts a list of words, and returns and a function that you can use with the text:

```js
const wordCount = (words) => (layers) => 
  words.reduce((c, w) => 
    layers.includes(w) ? c + 1 : c, 
    0);
  
const count = wordCount(['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']);

const result = count('Layer 1, Text1');

console.log(result) // 1
```

A Nashorn compatible version:

```js
function wordCount(words) {
  var found = 0;
  return function(layers) {
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if(layers.includes(words[i])) found += 1;
    }
  
    return found;
  }
}

var count = wordCount(['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3']);

var result = count('Layer 1, Text1');

console.log(result) // 1
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but unfortunately i'm using Nashorn and it doesn't have arrow function capability so it doesn' work on my end :-( This is the result i get: java.lang.AsertioError: Failed generating bytecode for <eval> :5. Is there a way you can re-write the code using nashorn capable language? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the keywords, and if it matches `layers` increment a counter.

```js
function wordCount(textString) {
  let keywords = ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4', 'Text5'];
  let count = 0;
  keywords.forEach(function(keyword) {
    if (textString.includes(keyword)) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
console.log(wordCount('Layer 1, Text1'));
```

Comment: I think what you have works the best, but as I've mentioned in the first answer my system doesn't support arrow functions. Could you kindly dumb it down? LOL. Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Comment: I've updated the answer. But the translation between arrow functions and normal functions is trivial, surely you could do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep your key words in a static array and interrogate any given string for a match count? There's still a little work to do here since it would need to be smart enough to handle punctuation. A regex could handle that part pretty easily.

```js
const getWordCount = (phrase, keywords) => {
    if (phrase) {
        phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
        const phraseArray = phrase.split(' ');
        let count = 0;
        phraseArray.forEach( (word) => {
            if ( keywords.find( k => k.toLowerCase() === word) ) {
                return count += 1;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
    return 0;
};
const str = 'This is my sentence. There are many like it, but this one is mine';
const count = getWordCount(str, ['like', 'are', 'this']);

console.log(count);
```